# SideBySide Event ID 63 Error ~ Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-event-log, sql-server-2014

I am getting the following repeating errors in event viewer:

[image]

Does anybody know what is causing these errors and how to fix them?

Answer (score 0):

SideBySide errors are usually caused when the executable requires a certain Visual Studio Runtime which doesn't exist, although I'm not 100% confident that this is the case here. How often does this error occur?

The screenshot is not sorted by date. Does it cause any issues? Often, these errors can be ignored without any harm.